# Programmatically execute VACUUM command using Sqlite3 and C++?

Tags: c++, sqlite, vacuum

I am trying to programmatically execute the `VACUUM` command in C++ using the Sqlite3 library for C++. See reference at [C-language Interface Specification for SQLite](https://sqlite.org/capi3ref.html).

Can someone give a code snippet of how to do this? I tried calling this but it gives an exception:

This code is in my SqliteDb.cpp helper class.

```
void SqliteDb::executeSql(const string& sqlStatement) {
  char* errMsg = NULL;
  sqlite3_exec(db, sqlStatement.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
  if (errMsg != NULL) {
    string reason = string("Error in") + sqlStatement + " " + errMsg;
    sqlite3_free(errMsg);
    __throw_sqlitedb(reason);
  }
}
```

In my main class I did:

```
try{
    db = new SqliteDb(filepath);
    db->executeSql("VACUUM;");
} catch (std::exception e) {
    printf("EXCEPTION occurred %s", e.what());
}
```

The output is

```
EXCEPTION occurred std::exception
```

The SqliteDb.cpp is a tested class and works well for other components that use this class.

Comment: Consider adding a [mcve], and include the error!

Comment: Added some sample code.

Comment: `VACUUM;` works for me in SQLite 3.22.0. Perhaps `filepath` is wrong. Maybe you should `string reason = ...;` and then `throw std::runtime_error(reason.c_str())`. It should allow you to catch something meaningful. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

you can use sqlite3_exec() api from sqlite3.

`sqlite3_exec(db, "VACUUM", 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score -3):

```
PRAGMA auto_vacuum = FULL;
```

Then you won't have to worry about it.